# What are the possible surfaces that one can construct from a finite set ot triangles?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tiling, discrete-geometry, triangulation

I am looking for references in discrete differential geometry for a concept I've been interested in.

It is very common to approximate smooth surfaces using discrete triangulations. I am interested in the opposite problem. I start off with edges of prescribed lengths, which I can use to form triangles, and I want to know which discrete surfaces I can from these triangles (I can use a given triangle more than once).

This is similar to a tiling problem. I have a finite collection of possible tiles, but instead of trying to form shapes in the plane, and I want to know which surfaces I can construct from them.

This sounds like something which is probably already studied in discrete differential geometry, but I am not sure what are the relevant terms/names I need to know in order to google some existing works. Has anyone here ever come across this concept? If so, I'd be happy to hear.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you care about lengths of sides, when you say (a given triangle more than once)?

Comment: Yes, I care about the lengths.

Comment: Oh, then I think you should make it explicit in your question. And, in this case, I guess you are asking about embeddings in euclidean space? This should be explicit too.

Answer (score 0):

I took a course and take part in a research project concerning simplicial surfaces. This structure sounds pretty familiar to your description. However, this research project rather takes an algebraic/combinatorial route when talking about simplicial surfaces rather than a view from differential geometry. For a taste, here is the first introduction of our lecture notes from the course:

> Background:
> In this course we study surfaces composed of triangles. The Platonic solids
> have been studied since antiquity. Among these, the surfaces of three of
> these are made up of triangles, namely the tetrahedron, the octahedron,
> and the icosahedron. These surfaces are our first and most famous examples
> of surfaces composed of triangles, namely simplicial surfaces. One feature
> of these three Platonic solids is also that the triangles of these surfaces are
> congruent to one particular triangle. We call this the control triangle. In
> this course we will put particular emphasis on simplicial surfaces for which
> all triangles are congruent to a control triangle.
> One motivation why we might be interested in these types of surfaces
> arises from potential applications: If one triangle in a realisation of this
> surface is damaged and needs replacing, this is easy to do, as one can
> stockpile spare copies of the control triangle.
> Surface triangulations are also ubiquitous in many applications, notably
> in computer graphics. Here it is important that a simplicial surface ap-
> proximates a given (smooth) surface as good as possible. To achieve such
> a good approximation, usually the triangulated surfaces consist of a huge
> number of individual triangles and these triangles are all different. There
> is a large body of literature devoted to these types of surface triangulations
> and there are many powerful computational tools, often using sophisticated
> numerical methods.
> In this course we will not deal with the question of approximating a
> given surface by a simplicial surface. We take the opposite approach and
> study simplicial surfaces, often together with a control triangle, from a
> purely combinatorial and algebraic point of view. We endeavor to discover
> the combinatorial principles guiding such surfaces and to understand their
> structure. We will find algebraic descriptions of such surfaces and aim to
> classify those with a small number of faces. We ask ourselves how a surface
> changes, when we change the congruence type of the control triangle. Our
> explorations are supported by the package SimplicialSurfaces, which is
> currently under development and is a package for the computational algebra
> system GAP.

If you are interested in this subject, I could contact someone who can share the current draft of the book they are writing for this subject. For other information, here is the [package for GAP](https://github.com/gap-packages/SimplicialSurfaces), where one can do a lot of stuff with simplicial surfaces.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am looking for a more geometric approach.